# MySQL stored procedure called from PHP script not returning results

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure to be executed by php, the actual SQL output works fine in my SQL manager [SQLYog] but does not return any results in the PHP script.

Reading the docs it seems that I had to declare some OUT variables in order for this to work, which I have done - but it's still not returning results.

See my code below:

```
while ($row = $results->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {

    $depth = $parentDepth;

    $cid = $row['id'];

    $ultimatesql = "DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS getParentArray;

    CREATE PROCEDURE getParentArray(IN cid INT, IN target INT, OUT parent_id_array VARCHAR(255), OUT my_parent VARCHAR(255))

    BEGIN

        DECLARE pid INT;
        DECLARE parent_id_array VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT '';
        DECLARE my_parent VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT '';

        REPEAT

            SET pid = (SELECT `sc`.`parent` FROM `modx_site_content` `sc` WHERE `id` = cid);

            SET parent_id_array = CONCAT(pid,',',parent_id_array);

            SET cid = pid;

        UNTIL cid = 0 END REPEAT;

        SET my_parent = (SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX((SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(parent_id_array, ',', target)), ',', -1));

        IF my_parent = '' 

            THEN SET my_parent = -1; 

        END IF;

        SELECT parent_id_array , target , my_parent;

    END;

    CALL getParentArray($cid, $depth, @out_a, @out_b);";

$statement = $modx->prepare($ultimatesql);

// The SQL echoed here works - results get returned if pasted into SQL studio 
echo '<pre>';print_r($statement);echo '</pre>';

$statement->execute();


while($result = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){

    // no results get returned here, 
    echo '<br> my result = ' . print_r($result);echo '<br>';

}

}
```

I'm not seeing what I am doing wrong, any idea why this is not returning a recordset?

Comment: I don't think PDO supports multiple statements

Comment: not seeing any errors... ?

Comment: To execute multiple queries at once, try setting  `$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, true);` right after PDO instantiation

Comment: Dealing with a modx system here: $modx->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, true); doesn't seem to help.

Comment: @SeanKimball dont put your whole stored procedure in code, transfer it in your sql,
simply call it in your code. `CALL <storedproc>`

Comment: @maku - docs or examples? this is a shared server, I did try to find a way to determine if the procedure existed before dropping & recreating it, but not much luck :(  I think it has to exist somewhere/somehow in the php it's not really part of a package or anything.

Comment: @SeanKimball i mean u should create your stored procedure in your database, and just call it in your code, based on experience you cannot execute multiple queries at once in php side.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like Fabricator is right on the money - if I break it up like this it all works fine [though seems a little messy :(]

```
$drop_proc = "DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS getParentArray;";

$create_proc = " CREATE PROCEDURE getParentArray(IN cid INT, IN target INT, OUT parent_id_array VARCHAR(255), OUT my_parent VARCHAR(255))

    BEGIN

        DECLARE pid INT;
        DECLARE parent_id_array VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT '';
        DECLARE my_parent VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT '';

        REPEAT

            SET pid = (SELECT `sc`.`parent` FROM `modx_site_content` `sc` WHERE `id` = cid);

            SET parent_id_array = CONCAT(pid,',',parent_id_array);

            SET cid = pid;

        UNTIL cid = 0 END REPEAT;

        SET my_parent = (SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX((SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(parent_id_array, ',', target)), ',', -1));

        IF my_parent = '' 

            THEN SET my_parent = -1; 

        END IF;

        SELECT parent_id_array , target , my_parent;

    END;";

$run_proc = "CALL getParentArray($cid, $depth, @out_a, @out_b);";


// drop the proc if exists
$drop_statement = $modx->prepare($drop_proc);

$drop_statement->execute();


// create a new one
$create_statement = $modx->prepare($create_proc);

$create_statement->execute();


// run it!
$run_statement = $modx->prepare($run_proc);

$run_statement->execute();


while($result = $run_statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    // now this works
    echo '<br> my result = ' . print_r($result);echo '<br>';

}
```